# How can I write an always-on "Quit" option in Python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, keyword, exit

I'm learning Python and am writing a basic "user profile manager." This program will be able to add, edit or delete user accounts to/from an existing file that contains saved user accounts. I've got it set up so that the person using the program goes through a series of questions to complete adding, editing or deleting (the whole thing is text based). I'm wondering if there's a way I can have each question be listening for a 'quit' keyword, that would close the user manager program, without having to put in an *if* statement for 'quit' in each individual question. Here's the code for the *delete user* ability:

```
action1 = input("Currently saved users:\n" +
                    # userList is a dictionary containing saved users
                    str(userList.keys()) +
                    "\nEnter the name of the profile you would like to delete.\n"
                    ).lower()

    # Prevent the built in Admin and Guest users from being modified
    while action1 == "guest" or action1 == "admin":
        print("Sorry, this profile cannot be modified. Please try again.")
        action1 = input("Enter the name of the profile you would like to delete.\n").lower()

    # Require the active user's password to complete the deletion process (if active user has a password)
    if user.password != None:
        delpass = input("Please enter your password to complete this action:\n")
        while delpass != user.password:
            delpass = input("Incorrect password for %s. Please try again:\n" %user.username)
    else:
        pass

    # Make sure one more time that the active user is sure about deletion
    action2 = input("Are you sure you want to delete this user profile?\n").lower()

    # Delete the selected user profile (which is action1)
    if action2 == "yes":
        del userList[action1]
        print("User " + action1 + " has been deleted from saved users.")
    else:
        print("Deletion of user " + action1 + " has been cancelled.")
```

Is there any way I can make it so that you can answer any of the questions with 'quit' and it will close the user manager, without adding an *if* statement for each individual question? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the `input()` function into your own function, and put the condition check in there:

```
def custom_input(question):
    answer = input(question).lower()
    if answer == 'quit':
        sys.exit() # or whatever you want to do
    return answer
```

^ then call this function instead of the `input()` function

above that - I would also recommend you to use a database for easier management of the user records instead of a text file, and hash your passwords, so they wont be stored as a plain-text.